# Rails - remote destroy method not rendering view partial : NoMethodError undefined method `id' for Photo

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, destroy

I'm getting the following error when trying to remotely delete an image in a view:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<Photo::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007fa826898200>):
  app/views/photos/destroy.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_photos_destroy_js_erb__997641922821004789_70180135669200'
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:31:in `destroy'
```

The following is my `destroy` method:

```
def destroy 
    @photo_destroy = Photo.find_by_id(params[:id])
    @item = Item.find(@photo_destroy.item_id)
    if @photo_destroy.present?
        @photo_destroy.destroy
    end
    flash[:success] = "Photo deleted"
    @photo = @item.photos
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to edit_photos_url(@item)}
        format.js
    end
end
```

And my destroy javascript:

```
$("#photo-<%= @photo.id %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('photos/showpics')) %>");
```

And the view partial:

```
<div class="row">
<% @photo.each do |photo| %>
<li id="photo-<%= photo.id %>">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail" >
            <%= image_tag photo.image_url(:thumb) if photo.image? %>
      <div class="caption">
                <%= photo.title %>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button"><%= link_to 'Remove', delete_photo_path(photo), method: :delete, remote: true %></a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </li>
 <% end %>
</div>
```

It seems to me that the `@photo` in the view partial isn't linking for lack of better term with the destroy in the `destroy` method. Now that i think about it, can the `@photo` from the method be passed to the javascript ? Or what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your traceback - putting them in comments is hard to read and they're not guaranteed to stay around. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was assigning an id to the `row` class in the `showpics` partial:

`<div class="row" id="photo-row">`

Changing the javascript:

`$("#photo-row").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('photos/showpics')) %>");`

And now all the photos get updated correctly when one of them was deleted. Thanks everyone else for your help.

Answer (score 0):

#### updated based on comment.

Look what you did:
Your `@photo` is a Photo::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy and you are calling where you are assigning `@item.photos`.

In order to get your partial works you need to get the id of your deleted object. Here it is:

```
 $("#photo-<%= @photo_destroy.id %>").html("<%= j render 'photos/showpics', {photos: @photo} ) %>");
```

#### you need to update your partial file as well:

```
<div class="row">
 <% photos.each do |photo| %>  # look at that photos, it comes from the local when we render it in j render 'photos/showpics', {photos: @photo}
  <li id="photo-<%= photo.id %>">  
  ....
```

This should works!

Comment: This works strictly speaking, but I'm trying to render the whole `showpics` section. This replaces the last deleted picture with the one before it, resulting in two identical pictures, until the user refreshes the `edit_photos` section. Any clue how I can fix this ?

Comment: you meant your rending showpicts section not working right? I understand the issue. Should I write another answer?